# Compile time triggered range check for std::vector

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

**The goal:**

I would like to have a range checked version of `std::vector`'s `operator []` for my debug builds and no range check in release mode.

The range check in debug mode is obviously good for debugging, but it causes a slowdown of 5% - 10% in my release code which I would like to avoid.

**Possible solutions:**

I found a solution in Stroustrup's "The C++ programming language". He did the following:

```
template <class T>
class checked_vector : public std::vector<T> {
    public:
        using std::vector<T>::vector;

        //override operator [] with at()
};
```

This is problematic because it inherits from a class with non-virtual destructor which is dangerous. (And [the Lounge](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16962889#16962889) [was not too](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16962905#16962905) [fond of that solution](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/16962927#16962927).)

Another idea would be a class like this:

```
template <class T>
class checked_vector {
    std::vector<T> data_;

    public:
        //put all public methods of std::vector here by hand

};
```

This would be both tedious and create a large amount of copy-paste which is bad too.

The nice thing about both the above solutions is that I can simply toggle them on and off with a macro definition in my makefile.

**The questions:**

1. Is there a better solution? (If not, why not?)
2. If not, is one of the above considered acceptable? (I know this one is opinion based, please focus on No. 1 if possible.)

Comment: I think Stoustrup's solution was meant to be used in the first couple weeks of teaching for something that just works with minimal hassle (what student is going to be using a vector polymorphically then?)

Comment: If you don't need runtime polymorphism, private inheritance might be an option.

Comment: Would you mind adding the page number? I'd like to read the context. Nevermind, found it in 4.4.1.2

Comment: Have you checked your standard library implementation? MSVC's, for instance, already does this in Debug builds.

Comment: @Praetorian As does libstdc++, not sure about libc++

Comment: @Praetorian I would prefer to toggle the rangecheck myself.

Comment: @juanchopanza Wouldn't I need a `using ...` for every member then?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Only one per name, not per member. So it is tedious, but not as much as your second solution.

Comment: @juanchopanza Hm, then that beats the first two I guess.

Comment: Although not guaranteed by the standard, I think non-virtual destructors are safe in practice as long as you don't add any data members and use the default destructor in the derived class.

Comment: A free function might be an option. Something like `template <typename T> const T& at(const vector<T>& v, int index) { return v.at(index); }` or the function body could look like `return v[index];` if `NDEBUG` is defined. The least amount of hassle, highly likely to be inlined (no overhead).

Comment: @Mark Ransom Isn't calling the wrong destructor undefined behavior regardless of whether it appears to work?

Comment: While I generally would agree that deriving from a class with a non-virtual destructor is not good practice, do you plan on holding these objects as pointers to the base class (`std::vector<T>*`)?

Comment: @MarkB yes, that's why I started my comment the way I did. The real answer of course is to never use such a class polymorphically. I'm just saying you're unlikely to get in trouble even if you screw up.

Comment: Note that the comments you linked to don't say anything about the lack of a virtual destructor (indeed, you had never even mentioned it at this point), so your use of the word "thus" in the question is misleading.

Comment: The Lounge is not known for its "fondness of things".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, this is the usual situation with Visual Studio.  With g++, you have to invoke the compiler with `-D_GLIBCXX_CONCEPT_CHECKS -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC`. (It's probable that you don't need all three, but I use all
three systematically.)  With other compilers, check the documentation.  The purpose of the undefined behavior in the standard here is precisely to allow this sort of thing.

Comment: With Clang + libc++, there was an experimental undertaking (`_LIBCPP_DEBUG`), however it did not pan out, and with the advent of ASan and the like it may be low-priority now.

Answer (score 4):

In decreasing order of preference:

- If you utilize iterators, ranges, and iteration rather than indexes into the container, the problem just goes away because you are no longer passing in arbitrary indexes that need to be checked. At that point you may decide to replace any remaining code that requires indexes with `at` instead of using a special container.
- Extend with algorithms rather than inheritance as suggested in one of the comments. This will almost certainly be completely inlined away and is consistent with the standard using algorithms rather than additional member functions. It also has the advantage of working with any container that has `operator[]` and `at` (so it would also work on `deque`):

  ```
  template <typename Container>
  const typename Container::value_type& element_at(const Container& c, int index)
  {
      // Do checked code here.
  }
  ```
- Privately inherit `std::vector` and `using` the methods you need into your child class. Then at least you can't improperly polomorphically destroy your child vector.

Comment: Note: if you use iterators, you might accidentally use invalidated ones though, so it's not exactly a panacea.

Comment: I would put into the first position: *Use whatever debugging facility is provided with your Standard Library implementation. Both gcc and MSVC already provide what you need.*

Comment: Iterators do not solve the problem.  Ranges do, but iterators themselves don't.

Comment: @MooingDuck Are you saying that ranges cannot be invalidated by operations on the underlying container?

Comment: @DDrmmr: Hah! True.  I was thinking read-only ranges, but realistically there's holes even there.