# how to enforce vector subscript out of range debug assertion on linux

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++

This code works on linux.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


int main () 
{
    vector<int> v(10, 0);

    cout << v[100];

    return 0;
}
```

operator[] is declared with a comment

```
      // element access
      /**
       *  @brief  Subscript access to the data contained in the %vector.
       *  @param __n The index of the element for which data should be
       *  accessed.
       *  @return  Read/write reference to data.
       *
       *  This operator allows for easy, array-style, data access.
       *  Note that data access with this operator is unchecked and
       *  out_of_range lookups are not defined. (For checked lookups
       *  see at().)
       */
      reference
      operator[](size_type __n) _GLIBCXX_NOEXCEPT
      { return *(this->_M_impl._M_start + __n); }
```

But MSVS compiler warns of such subscript-out-of-range cases. Is there any way to mimic it's behavior?

Comment: [Related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246017/compile-time-triggered-range-check-for-stdvector).

Comment: thx, is there anything similar for C (libc)?

Comment: Not that I know of.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, a colleague of mine had found the desired answer:

-D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG

flag activates debug mode for libstdc++.