# Use `.at()` instead of operator `[]` for std::vector in debug mode

Tags: c++, vector, operator-keyword, stdvector

If I try to access an `std::vector` out of bounds it will lead to undefined behaviour.

```
const std::vector<int> vec {1,2,3};
const int a = vec[4];
```

Nevertheless, this code will probably not fail immediately, but `a` will have an arbitrary value;

If `vec` is accessed via the method `.at()` an exception will be thrown.

```
const int a = vec.at(4);
```

The disadvantage is, that the performance will drop significantly if `.at()` is always used.

My question is, if some C++ compiler supports a compile flag, that switches the `operator []` to the `.at()` method.

Turing it on would lead to good debug-able code.
Turing it off would lead to a quick release executable.

I know that heap check tools , such as `valgrind` will find these bugs, but they take a lot of time.

Comment: You could write your own vector implementation, and switch by changing `using schorsch312::vector;` to `using std::vector;`.  Possibly using `#ifdef NDEBUG` around it.

Comment: I think you need to be specific about your compiler.  UB means the compiler can do anything it wants - like throw if it's been compiled in debug

Comment: MSVC already supports bounds checking for `operator[]` with debug.

Comment: which compiler are you working on? Because MSVC already does it while Clang (eg macOS) can enable address sanitizer which covers this situaton.

Comment: @Clonk: because `at()` does bound checking also in release mode so it's an `O(k1)` different from `O(k2)` of `operator[]`. Complexity is the same but on millions of calls you can see a difference.

Comment: @Clonk Constant complexity only applies to algorithms.

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/q/24246017/3002139 Some Mjolnir should clean this up.